# Does django version 1.11 work with djongo package?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

When I try to run the server using django==1.11 I get this error.

```
from djongo import models

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/djongo/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .fields import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 28, in <module>
from django.db.models.fields.mixins import FieldCacheMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.models.fields.mixins'
```

But when I try doing the same using django==2 everything works fine.
Nothing regarding the Django version is given in the docs: https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/

The `requirements.txt` file in djongo on Github says it does support django==1.11.

```
sqlparse>=0.2.3
pymongo>=3.2.0
django>=1.11
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the issue was.Djongo package version==1.2.23 works with django==1.11

Answer (score 2):

The `django.db.models.fields.mixins` file is new in Django 2.0 (here is the [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/bfb746f983aa741afa3709794e70f1e0ab6040b5#diff-a25452482c66e7d44aaae93c73434d56) where it was added).

If djongo imports this file, then it doesn't support Django 1.11.

Comment: But the requirements.txt says it supports.

Comment: Then the requirements.txt is incorrect or out of date.